# Power BI columns to rows

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Looking for a bit of advice before I probably go down a long convoluted and unnecessary solution.

I have a source table of data that I'm bringing into PowerBI. The data consists of customer details. Let's say Column A (customer ref), B (customer age) and C (first name). However, some rows will have 2 customers and their details will show in the same row columns E,F,G. (max of 2 customers and say 50% of rows have one customer and 50% have two customers)

My aim is to create a table with only 3 columns (A,B,C), with details of the second customers appended below the first customer details (removing any blanks)

What would be the most simple approach to achieve this? I'm struggling to find a pivot/unpivot option and now thinking about splitting up into 2 tables and joining them up again. But that feels very clunky.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

I tried to use pivot.

Sorry, you guys are right, The images below should help. I'm trying to go from table 1 to table 2. Basically trying to stack the data in the last 3 columns under the data in the first 3 columns ( and remove blanks/null)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to provide some sample data and expected output in order for us to help.

Comment: post sample data. And where did column D go?

Comment: Sorry, you guys are right, The images below should help. I'm trying to go from table 1 to table 2. Basically trying to stack the data in the last 3 columns under the data in the first 3 columns ( and remove blanks/null)

Comment: Ref ID 1 Age 1 Gender 1 Ref ID 2 Age 2 Gender 2
1000 50              M 1001    49                  F
1002 40              M 1006     41          F
1007 55              F   
1008 60               F 1009      61         M

Comment: Ref ID Age Gender
1000 50 M
1002 40 F
1003 31 M
1005 42 M
1007 55 F
1008 60 F
1001 49 F
1004 33 M
1006 41 F
1009 61 M

Comment: And did this answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Ref ID 1", "Age 1", "Gender 1"}),
#"Removed Other Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Ref ID 2", "Age 2", "Gender 2"}),
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns2",List.Zip({{"Ref ID 2", "Age 2", "Gender 2"},{"Ref ID 1", "Age 1", "Gender 1"}})),
combined = #"Removed Other Columns1" & #"Rename",
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(combined, each ([Age 1] <> null))
in #"Filtered Rows"
```

Generic:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" =  Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
leading=0, groupsof=3,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Split( List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList( _),leading), groupsof) ),
#"Added Custom0" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom0", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Record.ToList(_),leading),"|")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom0",{"Custom0", "Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn( #"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Extracted Values", each ([Custom] <> "")),
#"Merged Columns" = if leading=0 then Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Custom0"}) else Table.CombineColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Custom0", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Custom"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),leading+groupsof))
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]